# No Bluetooth option using Lenovo a269i

Tags: bluetooth

I'm an android first timer, who bought a Lenovo a269i. Lenovo's site states that it has bluetooth, http://shopap.lenovo.com/in/en/smartphones/a-series/a269i/ and plenty others in Internet do so too.

However I don't know, or can't find, where to turn it on or anything. It's not discoverable (if it exists) as I tried with to find it with my computer. I downloaded some "Bluetooth Shortcut" apps, and they all crash, I think... they try to open but return me to where I originally was. It's using android 2.3.6

What can I do? How do I fix the bluetooth? Or how do I know for sure it doesn't have?

Comment: Have you checked `Settings->Wireless & networks->Bluetooth`?

Comment: I have Settings->(signal symbol) More...->(Wi-Fi options, VPN and tether are listed here, but no Bluetooth)

Comment: No. Bluetooth setting won't be under `more...`. You should check under `wireless & networks` [ http://www.myfreenetwork.com/images/android/02.jpg ].

Comment: @MinNaingOo I don't have that option. However, "More..." has the same menu icon, and it is just above "Call settings" (I don't have sound either, it's called "Audio profiles")